# Sourdough starter with milk vs just using regular starter and adding milk separately?

Tags: baking, bread, cake, milk, sourdough

How much of a difference would it make to the final product and which one would be the better choice for any enriched sourdough breads/pastries/cakes etc?  And by "regular starter" I mean the normal flour and water mixture.  Thanks!

Comment: I see that a lot of your questions are still open, you should mark as accepted the answer that best solves your problem, check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and take the [tour] to learn more about the site

Answer (score 1):

If it can be done, it will make lots of difference. Different sourdough recipes are geared towards breeding different bacterial species, which give their own taste to the final product.

There is no answer to "what will be a better choice". If you have a known good recipe for a starter using milk, then it is up to the eater to decide which result tastes better to them. It's literally a matter of taste.

Note that, if you just thought to pour some milk and flour together, this is a terrible idea. Fermented foods are only safe when following the recipe to the letter. A small change in the initial conditions can breed a completely different strain of bacteria - which can be simply yucky, but can also be seriously dangerous for your health. So if you don't have a trusted source which describes the exact way to produce a safe sourdough starter by using milk, don't experiment on your own.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but thanks a lot for your response! I never knew  sourdough could potentially be harmful, that's very interesting.   What recipe should I follow for a milk starter? Any tips or advice?   Thank you again.

Comment: I don't have tips on recipes, as I have never had a milk fed starter. Also, our site doesn't allow (main) questions asking for recipes. You will have to look around and find one you trust. Usually, there is not much information on why you should trust them, so I generally go by how good the source is, e.g. a printed book is better than a site with user submitted recipes.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway.   Hopefully it all turns out well for me!